# C# Recursive find file using Pattern

Tags: c#, file, directory

I have a Visual Studio solution with the following structure:

```
- root
 - src
  - project01
  - project02
 - config
  - application.config
  - database.dacpac
```

Now, assuming I am executing a code from the path:

```
C:\DEV\root\project01\bin\release\project01.exe
```

How can I find **the first occurrence** of the file "application.config" for example?

I know that I can start with this:

```
public string GetExecutingDirectory(){
{
   string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
   UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
   string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
   return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
}
```

And use it in the following way:

```
var executingDirectory = GetExecutingDirectory();
```

But now, how can I traverse the Root Tree back and forward until I find the file I am looking for?
I tried this code but it doesn't find anything:

```
var path = Directory
   .GetFiles(executingDirectory, 
      "**/application.config", 
      System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I need it because I am running Integration Tests from different paths and they need these files which can be in a different location of the solution tree depending on the DEV machine configuration so I need to use the "pattern" because the structure can be different from PC to PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
static string FindConfig()
{
    string appFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\DEV\root\project01\bin\release\project01.exe");
    string configPath = null;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(appFolder);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(appFolder, "*application.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ToLower().EndsWith(@"\application.config"))
            {
                return file;
            }
        }
        appFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(appFolder);
        if (appFolder.Length < 4) // "C:\" don't search root drive
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return configPath;
}
```